# ·What does the second sentence in this paragraph mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, negation, multiple-negation, negative-inversion

"If people had invested their money in antiques 20 years ago, they would have found it difficult to make a profit on their investment until very recently. So people who cannot afford for their savings not to increase should invest their money in something other than antiques."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antiques bought as an investment twenty years ago have only recently begun to increase in value. So, if you need a quick return on your investments, *don't* invest in antiques.